# GLFW/Vulkan Transparent Framebuffer does not respect swapchain source image alpha channel?

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I have a transparent enabled GLFW window, Vulkan Swapchain with `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR` and a Graphics Pipeline using Normal Blend `(Src * One) + (Dst * One_Minus_Src)`.

This is broken up into three parts, window/swapchain/graphicspipeline creation. See
also the Github for the project for more information: https://github.com/Yaazarai/TinyVulkan-Dynamic

The problem is this: The transparent framebuffer works, but it doesn't respect the alpha channel because the only supported swapchain composite alpha mode is `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR` which makes the framebuffer always have an alpha component of one when compositing multiple window surfaces.

I've gone through checked each composite mode and Vulkan always errors when `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR` isn't used. Changing the blend mode doesn't work either because well the framebuffer alpha component is always 1.

```
Validation Layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-compositeAlpha-01280 ] Object 0: handle = 0x2655f873250, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xb0051a12 | vkCreateSwapchainKHR() called with a non-supported pCreateInfo->compositeAlpha (i.e. VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_PRE_MULTIPLIED_BIT_KHR).  Supported values are:
    VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR
. The Vulkan spec states: compositeAlpha must be one of the bits present in the supportedCompositeAlpha member of the VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR structure returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR for the surface
```

```
// Creates a Vulkan Swapchain with the supported Surface Capabilities based
// on the GLFW Vulkan Window surface passed to the VkPhysicalDevice.
void CreateSwapChainImages(uint32_t width = 0, uint32_t height = 0) {
    TinyVkSwapChainSupporter swapChainSupport = QuerySwapChainSupport(renderDevice.physicalDevice);
    VkSurfaceFormatKHR surfaceFormat = QuerySwapSurfaceFormat(swapChainSupport.formats);
    VkPresentModeKHR presentMode = QuerySwapPresentMode(swapChainSupport.presentModes);
    VkExtent2D extent = QuerySwapExtent(swapChainSupport.capabilities);
    uint32_t imageCount = std::min(swapChainSupport.capabilities.maxImageCount, std::max(swapChainSupport.capabilities.minImageCount, static_cast<uint32_t>(bufferingMode)));

    if (width != 0 && height != 0) {
        extent = {
            std::min(std::max((uint32_t)width, swapChainSupport.capabilities.minImageExtent.width), swapChainSupport.capabilities.maxImageExtent.width),
            std::min(std::max((uint32_t)height, swapChainSupport.capabilities.minImageExtent.height), swapChainSupport.capabilities.maxImageExtent.height)
        };
    } else {
        extent = QuerySwapExtent(swapChainSupport.capabilities);
    }

    if (swapChainSupport.capabilities.maxImageCount > 0 && imageCount > swapChainSupport.capabilities.maxImageCount)
        imageCount = swapChainSupport.capabilities.maxImageCount;

    VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR createInfo{};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    createInfo.surface = renderDevice.presentationSurface;
    createInfo.minImageCount = imageCount;
    createInfo.imageFormat = surfaceFormat.format;
    createInfo.imageColorSpace = surfaceFormat.colorSpace;
    createInfo.imageExtent = extent;
    createInfo.imageArrayLayers = 1; // Change when developing VR or other 3D stereoscopic applications
    createInfo.imageUsage = imageUsage;

    TinyVkQueueFamily indices = TinyVkQueueFamily::FindQueueFamilies(renderDevice.physicalDevice, renderDevice.presentationSurface);
    uint32_t queueFamilyIndices[] = { indices.graphicsFamily.value(), indices.presentFamily.value() };

    if (indices.graphicsFamily != indices.presentFamily) {
        createInfo.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT;
        createInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 2;
        createInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = queueFamilyIndices;
    } else {
        createInfo.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
        createInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0; // Optional
        createInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr; // Optional
    }

    createInfo.preTransform = swapChainSupport.capabilities.currentTransform;
    createInfo.compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
    createInfo.presentMode = presentMode;
    createInfo.clipped = VK_TRUE;
    createInfo.oldSwapchain = swapChain;

    if (vkCreateSwapchainKHR(renderDevice.logicalDevice, &createInfo, nullptr, &swapChain) != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("TinyVulkan: Failed to create swap chain!");

    vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(renderDevice.logicalDevice, swapChain, &imageCount, nullptr);
    images.resize(imageCount);
    vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(renderDevice.logicalDevice, swapChain, &imageCount, images.data());

    imageFormat = surfaceFormat.format;
    imageExtent = extent;
}

// Creates the graphics pipeline with the appropriate Normal Blend mod
void CreateGraphicsPipeline() {
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////// This section specifies that MvkVertex provides the vertex layout description ///////////
    const VkVertexInputBindingDescription bindingDescription = vertexDescription.binding;
    const std::vector<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription>& attributeDescriptions = vertexDescription.attributes;

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputInfo{};
    vertexInputInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertexInputInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 1;
    vertexInputInfo.pVertexBindingDescriptions = &bindingDescription;
    vertexInputInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attributeDescriptions.size());
    vertexInputInfo.pVertexAttributeDescriptions = attributeDescriptions.data();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutInfo{};
    pipelineLayoutInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
                
    pipelineLayoutInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;
    uint32_t pushConstantRangeCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(pushConstantRanges.size());
    if (pushConstantRangeCount > 0) {
        pipelineLayoutInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = pushConstantRangeCount;
        pipelineLayoutInfo.pPushConstantRanges = pushConstantRanges.data();
    }

    if (descriptorBindings.size() > 0) {
        VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo descriptorCreateInfo{};
        descriptorCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
        descriptorCreateInfo.flags = VK_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_PUSH_DESCRIPTOR_BIT_KHR;
        descriptorCreateInfo.bindingCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(descriptorBindings.size());
        descriptorCreateInfo.pBindings = descriptorBindings.data();

        if (vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(renderDevice.logicalDevice, &descriptorCreateInfo, nullptr, &descriptorLayout) != VK_SUCCESS)
            throw std::runtime_error("TinyVulkan: Failed to create push descriptor bindings! ");

        pipelineLayoutInfo.setLayoutCount = 1;
        pipelineLayoutInfo.pSetLayouts = &descriptorLayout;
    }

    if (vkCreatePipelineLayout(renderDevice.logicalDevice, &pipelineLayoutInfo, nullptr, &pipelineLayout) != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("TinyVulkan: Failed to create graphics pipeline layout!");
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly{};
    inputAssembly.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    inputAssembly.topology = vertexTopology;
    inputAssembly.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState{};
    viewportState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
    viewportState.scissorCount = 1;
    viewportState.flags = 0;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer{};
    rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    rasterizer.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.polygonMode = polgyonTopology;
    rasterizer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
    rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;
    rasterizer.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampling{};
    multisampling.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    multisampling.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;
    multisampling.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending{};
    colorBlending.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    colorBlending.logicOpEnable = VK_FALSE;
    colorBlending.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY;
    colorBlending.attachmentCount = 1;

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState blendDescription = colorBlendState;
    colorBlending.pAttachments = &blendDescription;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f;

    const std::array<VkDynamicState, 2> dynamicStateEnables = { VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT, VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR };
    dynamicState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DYNAMIC_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    dynamicState.flags = 0;
    dynamicState.pDynamicStates = dynamicStateEnables.data();
    dynamicState.dynamicStateCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(dynamicStateEnables.size());
    dynamicState.pNext = nullptr;

    VkPipelineRenderingCreateInfoKHR renderingCreateInfo{};
    renderingCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RENDERING_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    renderingCreateInfo.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    renderingCreateInfo.pColorAttachmentFormats = &imageFormat;
    renderingCreateInfo.depthAttachmentFormat = QueryDepthFormat();

    VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo depthStencilInfo{};
    depthStencilInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DEPTH_STENCIL_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    depthStencilInfo.depthTestEnable = enableDepthTesting;
    depthStencilInfo.depthWriteEnable = enableDepthTesting;
    depthStencilInfo.depthCompareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS;
    depthStencilInfo.depthBoundsTestEnable = VK_FALSE;
    depthStencilInfo.minDepthBounds = 0.0f; // Optional
    depthStencilInfo.maxDepthBounds = 1.0f; // Optional
    depthStencilInfo.stencilTestEnable = VK_FALSE;
    depthStencilInfo.front = {}; // Optional
    depthStencilInfo.back = {}; // Optional

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo{};
    pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineInfo.stageCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(shaderStages.shaderCreateInfo.size());
    pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages.shaderCreateInfo.data();
    pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputInfo;
    pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
    pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
    pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
    pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
    pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlending;
    pipelineInfo.pDepthStencilState = &depthStencilInfo;

    pipelineInfo.pDynamicState = &dynamicState;
    pipelineInfo.pNext = &renderingCreateInfo;

    pipelineInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
    pipelineInfo.renderPass = nullptr;
    pipelineInfo.subpass = 0;
    pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE; // Optional
    pipelineInfo.basePipelineIndex = -1; // Optional

    if (vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(renderDevice.logicalDevice, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineInfo, nullptr, &graphicsPipeline) != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("TinyVulkan: Failed to create graphics pipeline!");
}

// Creates the GLFW transparent framebuffer enabled window.
TinyVkWindow(std::string title, int width, int height, bool resizable, bool transparentFramebuffer = false, bool hasMinSize = false, int minWidth = 200, int minHeight = 200) {
    onDispose.hook(callback<bool>([this](bool forceDispose){this->Disposable(forceDispose); }));
    onWindowResized.hook(callback<GLFWwindow*, int, int>([this](GLFWwindow* hwnd, int width, int height) { if (hwnd != hwndWindow) return; hwndWidth = width; hwndHeight = height; }));
    onWindowPositionMoved.hook(callback<GLFWwindow*, int, int>([this](GLFWwindow* hwnd, int xpos, int ypos) { if (hwnd != hwndWindow) return; hwndXpos = xpos; hwndYpos = ypos; }));

    hwndWindow = InitiateWindow(title, width, height, resizable, transparentFramebuffer);
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(hwndWindow, this);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(hwndWindow, TinyVkWindow::OnFrameBufferNotifyReSizeCallback);
    glfwSetWindowPosCallback(hwndWindow, TinyVkWindow::OnWindowPositionCallback);

    if (hasMinSize) glfwSetWindowSizeLimits(hwndWindow, minWidth, minHeight, GLFW_DONT_CARE, GLFW_DONT_CARE);

    InitGLFWInput();
}
```

So here's the weird bit, the transparent framebuffer works and so does the VkClearColor for the framebuffer to clear the window surface, but as stated the alpha component is ignored. Which means that the alpha component during surface compositing is determined by the value of the RGB components of the clear color, as seen below, given a clear color of dark purple (RGBA) `0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0`. The correct result should be clear with transparency and black with without due to a 0.0 alpha which isn't respected, so we get purple instead.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point here. Your implementation *told you* that it didn't support alpha transparency. That's why it only offers `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR` which explicitly says that it ignores the image's alpha.

Comment: @NicolBolas correct and I was trying to find a solution to that problem. Which I did, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I don't fully understand pre-multiplied alpha color math, but everything is actually working as expected (thanks Discord Graphics Programming). The problem is that with pre-multiplied alpha a zero-alpha component is NOT a valid color so the behavior is unexpected by the color compositer when rendering with the SwapChain--which as stated prior is because I cannot use `VK_COMPOSITE_PREMULITPLIED_ALPHA` on the SwapChain. The solution then is to use a render-to-texture model for rendering then output that to the SwapChain for the desired result.

However, if you want explicitly transparent windows (Idk for GIF recording apps or something), then premultiplied alpha is actually desirable because now your background clear color (as seen in image 2 below is premultiplied with the compositing clear background. Which is not the case when using render-to-texture then render-to-swapchain (image 1 directly below)--you'll notice the output image is darker because it was premultiplied with black with an image renderer.

This answer is courtesy of the Graphics Programming/Vulkan Discord community.

Reference: https://ciechanow.ski/alpha-compositing/

[image]

[image]